# Does all releases of Durandal.js support responsive website development

Tags: durandal

I want to use `Durandal.js` to make single page responsive webapp. Can I use any version of `Durandal.js` or should I use some specific version?

Answer (score 1):

Durandal is a SPA (or a large website that's dynamic in nature). Sites build using Durandal are responsive in their speed but not directly responsive to different browsers, resolutions and devices. This is handled by our friends at Bootstrap.

If you are making just one page advert for your company, use Bootstrap. If you're making a large application with many forms, questions and layouts, use Aurelia. Aurelia is a new shift on Durnadal that's using the latest design practices.

https://aurelia.io/home

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/